# При запросе AbstractCollectionPersister удаляет коллекцию, связь ManyToMany

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, hibernate

Пытаюсь сделать логин со связью ManyToMany, Hibernate. Но в момент загрузки пользователя по имени, коллекция (Set) ролей cначала успешно достается, а потом так же успешно удаляется  и, завершив сессию, уходит в закат, оставив меня ни с чем. (Spring 4, Hibernate 5, Spring Security 4)

Вот организация сущностей:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

private Integer id;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean enabled = true;
private Set<Role> roles =  new HashSet<Role>();

//Getters & Setters

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "enabled")
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> userRoles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + username.hashCode();
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof User))
        return false;
    User other = (User) obj;
    if (username == null) {
        if (other.username != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
        return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", enabled=" + enabled +
            ", roles=" + roles +
            '}';
}}
```

Класс Role и RoleEnum:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

private Integer id;
private String role = RolesEnum.USER.getUserRole();

//Getters & Setters

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer userId) {
    this.id = userId;
}

@Column(name = "role")
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + role.hashCode();
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Role))
        return false;
    Role other = (Role) obj;
    if (role == null) {
        if (other.role != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!role.equals(other.role))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", role='" + role + '\'' +
            '}';
}}


public enum RolesEnum {
USER("USER"),
ADMIN("ADMIN");

String userRole;

private RolesEnum(String userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

public String getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}}
```

В базе данных таблицы заполнены:
[image: Бд]

CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    com.alice.domain.User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    if(user==null){
        System.out.println("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
    System.out.println("User for login : "+ user.getUsername());

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles());

    return buildUserForAuthentification(user, authorityList);
}


private User buildUserForAuthentification(com.alice.domain.User user,
                                          List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList){
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;


    return new User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),user.isEnabled(),
            accountNonExpired ,credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorityList);

}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles){

    Set<GrantedAuthority> authoritySet = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    System.out.println("Уровень выборки");
    for(Role userRole: userRoles){
        authoritySet.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+ 
    userRole.getRole()));
        System.out.println("His role : "+ userRole);
    }
    return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(authoritySet);
}}
```

Поиск по имени дао:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User findByUsername(String username) {

    User user = getByName("from User where username=?", username);

    System.out.println("behold... "+ user.getUsername());
    return user;}

    //Реализация в общем дао
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T getByName(String query, String name){
    return (T) getSession().createQuery(query).setParameter(0, 
    name).uniqueResult();}
```

Логи из консоли:

```
    16:26:26.345 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - 
    Result row: EntityKey[com.alice.domain.User#1]
    16:26:26.384 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG                 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for 
    [com.alice.domain.User#1]
    16:26:26.425 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity 
    [com.alice.domain.User#1]
    16:26:26.431 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer 
    - Loading collection: [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
    16:26:26.431 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
    roles0_.user_id as user_id1_9_0_,
    roles0_.role_id as role_id2_9_0_,
    role1_.id as id1_6_1_,
    role1_.role as role2_6_1_ 
from
    user_role roles0_ 
inner join
    role role1_ 
        on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id 
where
    roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    roles0_.user_id as user_id1_9_0_,
    roles0_.role_id as role_id2_9_0_,
    role1_.id as id1_6_1_,
    role1_.role as role2_6_1_ 
from
    user_role roles0_ 
inner join
    role role1_ 
        on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id 
where
    roles0_.user_id=?
    16:26:26.437 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl - 
    Preparing collection intializer : [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
    16:26:26.447 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl - 
    Starting ResultSet row #0
    16:26:26.449 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal
    .CollectionReferenceInitializerI
    mpl - Found row of collection: [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
    16:26:26.452 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for 
    [com.alice.domain.Role#1]
    16:26:26.452 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity 
    [com.alice.domain.Role#1]
    16:26:26.452 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - 1 
    collections were found in result set for role: 
    com.alice.domain.User.roles
    16:26:26.453 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - Collection 
    fully initialized: [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
    16:26:26.453 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - 1 
    collections initialized for role: com.alice.domain.User.roles
    16:26:26.453 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - 
    HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
    16:26:26.453 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan
    .AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer- Done loading collection
    behold... lis
    User for login : lis
    Уровень выборки
    16:26:26.456 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager - 
    Initiating transaction commit
    16:26:26.456 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager - 
    Committing Hibernate transaction on Session 
    [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=
    [EntityKey[com.alice.domain.User#1], 
    EntityKey[com.alice.domain.Role#1]],collectionKeys=
    [CollectionKey[com.alice.domain.User.dictionarySet#1], 
    CollectionKey[com.alice.domain.User.roles#1],          
    CollectionKey[com.alice.domain.User.wordList#1]]];
    ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} 
    unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
    16:26:26.456 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
    16:26:26.458 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing 
    flush-time cascades
    16:26:26.463 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty 
    checking collections
    16:26:26.477 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - Collection found: 
    [com.alice.domain.User.dictionarySet#1], was: 
    [com.alice.domain.User.dictionarySet#1] (uninitialized)
    16:26:26.477 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - Collection found: 
    [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
    16:26:26.477 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - Collection found: 
    [com.alice.domain.User.wordList#1], was: 
    [com.alice.domain.User.wordList#1] (uninitialized)
    16:26:26.477 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections - Collection dereferenced: 
    [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
    16:26:26.478 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 
    insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
    16:26:26.478 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG                 
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 
   (re)creations, 0 updates, 1 removals to 4 collections
   16:26:26.480 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
   16:26:26.481 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - 
   com.alice.domain.User
   {password=$2a$10$Uch5QgeIMkDgHhMH0re9MutqV/tGYxl6XgSYpQRk.C1JG0xJIpCuG, 
   wordList=<uninitialized>, dictionarySet=<uninitialized>, roles=[], 
   telephone=333444, id=1, creation_date=2017-05-14 00:00:00.0, 
   email=mimi@gi.com, enabled=true, username=lis}
   16:26:26.481 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - 
   com.alice.domain.Role{role=ADMIN, id=1}
   16:26:26.525 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - Deleting 
   collection: [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
   16:26:26.537 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
   delete 
     from
      user_role 
   where
     user_id=?
   Hibernate: 
   delete 
   from
    user_role 
    where
    user_id=?
   16:26:26.538 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - Done 
   deleting collection
   16:26:26.538 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - 
   Inserting collection: [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
   16:26:26.538 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - 
   Collection was empty
   16:26:26.546 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing 
   Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=
   [EntityKey[com.alice.domain.User#1], 
   EntityKey[com.alice.domain.Role#1]],collectionKeys=
   [CollectionKey[com.alice.domain.User.dictionarySet#1], 
   CollectionKey[com.alice.domain.User.wordList#1], 
   CollectionKey[com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]]];
   ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} 
   unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] after transaction
   16:26:26.546 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - HHH000420: 
   Closing un-released batch
   16:26:26.651 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG 
   org.springframework.security.web
   .authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy 
   - Delegating to 
   org.springframework.security.web
   .authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthentic
   ationStrategy@5369c6b8
```

Пробовала менять eager на lazy, но в не зависимости подтянута она или нет, все равно удаляется. В equals() и hashcode() поместила для проверки имя пользователя(меняться не будет). Есть смутное сомнение, что загвоздка именно в них, так как использую HashSet, но где именно не знаю. Еще были предположения,что проблема может возникать от места инициализации сета(это реально?).
Помогите плиз, заранее спасибо=)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что где-то происходит удаление элементов коллекции `User.roles`, но в приведённом коде я этого не нашёл - вероятно, не все сопутствующие процессу исходные коды приведены в вопросе. Вот сообщения в логе об этом:

```
Collection dereferenced: [com.alice.domain.User.roles#1]
...
...roles=[]...
...
delete from user_role...
```

похоже на то, что коллекция `roles` у объекта `User` где-то подменяется целиком на пустую коллекцию.

Comment: Вроде привела весь код, в котором как-либо участвует роль. Черт знает, в любом случае, спасибо большое, пойду дальше искать.